# How do I add an Andrioid NDK-built shared library to my APK without using NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-native-library

Pretty much exact duplicate of [Add a native lib to an APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365227/add-a-native-lib-to-an-apk). Since there was no answer I decided to ask again.

I have an Android project. I have an .so library built with android NDK. And I want to use this .so in my project, preferrably - without using NDK.

So, how do I tell Eclipse (or Android tools) that I need certain .so to be built into my APK?

Comment: I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse) will help u to find ur answer.

Comment: Please don't add tags to your question title, thats what the normal tags are for.

Comment: @alextsc: it's not a tag, it's a word that clearly specifies the context of the question and makes the title more clear, what's wrong with that?..

Comment: It's redundant: The title says it's an android question. The primary tag says the same. Also try to browse the android tag with lots of these titles, the list looks like "Android: X", "Android: Y", "Android: Z". It's just unneccessary and anoying when browsing for a question to answer by scanning the titles.

Comment: @alextsc: Now I see your reason, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually easier than I expected. All I had to do is place the `.so` in **libs/armeabi-v7a** - Eclipse saw it and integrated into APK.

However, I've made this project by copying from another Eclipse project, which was actually building this .so from source. So, I think there were some settings that I would otherwise need to set. Feel free to add corrections or edit my answer.

Comment: I am doing similar things. But my another library is not compiled for ARM its compiled for another architure so its not elf format still yet i want to add that in apk so by doing that i get error like "arm-linux-androideabi-strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file" so its delete that library and make apk without that library. DO you know how to stop this?

Comment: @Mr.32: I don't, I have no experience with multiarch APKs. I suggest you post a question.

Comment: add a .so file from directory outside android project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713933/add-so-prebuilt-library-from-another-directory-to-apk