# How can I add a '.so' library in my android project

Tags: android-ndk

I am a beginer in android.Now I am woking with an app that use native libraries.I need to know how to add a '.so' library file in my android project.Any one please help me.

Comment: A perfect duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295728/how-to-add-a-shared-library-to-my-apk

Comment: Another duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882167/creating-a-product-sdk-how-do-i-add-a-native-lib-so-and-a-jar-with-the-sdk-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after making your native c code and header file browse to the root directory of your project and run **ndk-build** command.That will generate the .so file and then place it inside your project/libs folder

Comment: I already have the so file from client.Can I get a solution while putting this file in the libs folder?

Comment: its recomended to build everytime there's a change in the native code,so if you no changes have been list last build you can add that to libs but if there are new changes try building again using ndk-build