# How to add a shared library to my APK with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

This is the same question, as [How to add a shared library to my APK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295728/how-to-add-a-shared-library-to-my-apk) but i want to know how to do the same with Android Studio, not Eclipse.

There is very obscure documentation on this topic:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html
It says roughly "Give the module a name, change Android.mk" but there is no info on what is a module, how to find it or add it, and where is the Android.mk.

Comment: this may help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio

Comment: Android.mk is the file used by ndk-build. All of the docs under https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html are for ndk-build, so if you're using gradle or cmake they won't be helpful.

Comment: The link by @Tasos is really outdated.