# Android Studio - Add shared library (.so) file and header (.h) file to project

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

I am currently working on an android project that requires me to make use of functions included in a shared library (.so). I also only have header (.h) files for the library provided to me.

Is it possible to work with just these two files? Or do I need to create my own implemenations via c++ codes?

I am using Android Studio intend to use CMake.

Regards,

Philip

Comment: Looks like [this blog](https://kvurd.com/blog/compiling-a-cpp-library-for-android-with-android-studio/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Yes.  You'd add the .so as a shared library, then build an JNI layer in both C and Java to access the .so library through the header's api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a shared library to my APK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295728/how-to-add-a-shared-library-to-my-apk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Android apps are written in Java. Google has released the Native Developer Kit (NDK) in order to allow developers to write libraries in C++. However, these libraries are usually very low level and called from the Java code which defines the UI and higher-level app logic. Most likely you will need to write a wrapper for the library so that you can call it from Java code. Looks like [this blog](https://kvurd.com/blog/compiling-a-cpp-library-for-android-with-android-studio/) is a good place to start.